# IOS Facebook SDK 3.17: Doesn't give me publish_stream permissions (while older versions as well as android both work -- so it is sdk specific)

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

The IOS Facebook SDK (3.17) doesn't give me publish_stream permissions (while older iOS versions and also android work fine -- so it is sdk specific)

What I do is straight forward

1 I get readPermissions
`[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {`

...

2 Later I call requestPublishPermissions

`[[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:nil];`

3 I do a NSLog => no publish_X permissions (I can get publish_actions but thats it)

`NSLog(@"%@", session);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB support:

Hi

Publish_stream and Publish_actions have been streamlined into just "publish_actions". You can read about it here at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph and at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1

Note that you will have to get your app approved by submitting it for review before you can use these permissions with users other than your test users and admins of your app.

Apps that have been granted publish_streams permissions will continue to work the same way as before.